# Rendering Meteor Templates in React Components

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-blaze

Lets stay I have a **loginbutton.html** file with template {{loginButton}}.

```
<template name="loginButton">
   //rest of code
</template>
```

How could I render this in a react component. I've looked around and found a couple of answers but to be honest I need more guidance bc I'm fairly new to Meteor. Below is a link to a possible answer I found. I just don't know how to implement this or if this is what i'm actually looking for.

https://gist.github.com/emdagon/944472f39b58875045b6

Comment: Just curious, is it that hard to convert it to jsx? (and benefit from the react virtual dom)

Comment: No but I want to add some specific auto-form meteor functionality from the iOS Camera that only works with Blaze rendering

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue. If you're trying to use a blaze template in a react component you have to make sure your meteor app is using "templating" on the client side (and in a package which is what I was using). Afterwards just follow the directions from the link above when creating your component passing the template in as a prop:

```
Base.components.photoButton = React.createClass({

componentDidMount: function() {

    var componentRoot = React.findDOMNode(this);

    var parentNode = componentRoot.parentNode;

    parentNode.removeChild(componentRoot);

    this.view = Blaze.render(this.props.template, parentNode);

},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
    // Clean up Blaze view
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
},

render: function() {

    return (<div/>

) 

},

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice atmosphere package [blazetoreact](https://atmospherejs.com/thereactivestack/blazetoreact).

It's very simple. If you have this Blaze template:

```html
<template name="loginButton">
   <!-- rest of code -->
</template>
```

Then you can use it as React component:

```js
const LoginButton = BlazeToReact('loginButton');

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LoginButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually didn't see this. This is pretty cool man. I'm going to try it out sometime this weekend although I solved the problem already.